# Go broken import

Tags: go

I'm trying to interact with helm via the go SDK and I'm getting the following error when I try to build my code:

```
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/deislabs/oras@v0.11.1/pkg/oras/push.go:52:31: not enough arguments in call to remotes.PushContent
        have (context.Context, remotes.Pusher, v1.Descriptor, "github.com/containerd/containerd/content".Store, nil, func(images.Handler) images.Handler)
        want (context.Context, remotes.Pusher, v1.Descriptor, "github.com/containerd/containerd/content".Store, *semaphore.Weighted, platforms.MatchComparer, func(images.Handler) images.Handler)
```

I've traced it down to package `helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action` :

```
$ go get helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action
# github.com/deislabs/oras/pkg/oras
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/deislabs/oras@v0.11.1/pkg/oras/push.go:52:31: not enough arguments in call to remotes.PushContent
        have (context.Context, remotes.Pusher, v1.Descriptor, "github.com/containerd/containerd/content".Store, nil, func(images.Handler) images.Handler)
        want (context.Context, remotes.Pusher, v1.Descriptor, "github.com/containerd/containerd/content".Store, *semaphore.Weighted, platforms.MatchComparer, func(images.Handler) images.Handler)
```

I suspect that this is related to this change: https://github.com/helm/helm/commit/663c5698878c959805de053116581d15673e1ce3

How do I fix this? I've tried using older versions of the helm package to no avail.

Comment: Looks like this is due to changes in `github.com/containerd/containerd` between v1.4 and v1.5 (the [`go.mod` for `github.com/deislabs/oras@v0.11.1`](https://github.com/oras-project/oras/blob/v0.11.1/go.mod#L16) specifies version `1.4.4` which be OK). `go get helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action` completes successfully on my machine; what version of go are you using and what is `GO111MODULE` set to (run `go env` to check this).

Answer (score 1):

The signature for `github.com/containerd/containerd/remotes.PushContent` was changed incompatibly in [commit f8c2f0](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/commit/f8c2f0475678a8fa2259ae26953627143b90024c), which was released in `v1.5.0`. (The `containerd` Go API appears to be unstable, despite its apparently-semantic version `v1.5.5`; see [containerd#3554](https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3554).)

The short-term fix is to `go get -d github.com/containerd/containerd@v1.4` to downgrade to the latest `v1.4.*` until your dependencies are compatible with the latest release.

The longer-term fix appears to be `helm` [commit 663c56](https://github.com/helm/helm/commit/663c5698878c959805de053116581d15673e1ce3), which migrates to a different `oras` library whose latest release is compatible with the `containerd` v1.5 API. As far as I can tell that commit has not yet been included in a `helm` release, but you may be able to try it out using `go get -d helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action@main`; see https://golang.org/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#repo_identifier.

Comment: Both approaches are functional!
Would prefer however that the [longterm fix](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/9970) is merged in

Comment: You can always upgrade any dependency to a higher version yourself, using `go get` in your own module. (`663c56` was the important change because it updated the code to use the new import path, which you can then upgrade at will.)